# Buying stuff and keeping it for later to sell it on a higher price?

Tags: fiqh, business

I am in the process of buying domain names and then later on selling them for a higher price- assuming someone is willing to pay for them.

What is the ruling on snapping up something undervalued and later, within a few months or years, selling them for a higher price? I have heard somewhere that this kind of trading is considered Haram in Islam because it's against the fair market value and will be taking unfair advantage from people's needs.

Comment: good question... for food this would definitely haram... another aspect: it might be a sort of gambling which is haram too... "trade" is basically buying at price x and selling at price x+y... and trade is generally allowed...

Comment: one thing to keep in mind: if what you bought is a long time in your possession then it might be necessary to pay zakat on it (based on current market value).

Comment: Do you know you will be getting a higher price for it? The way you have described this transaction, it sounds like a form of gambling to me.

Comment: How can this possibly be haraam?  If I buy some oranges, and sell them for the same price, how will I earn a living.  The whole point of trade is to buy it for less and sell it for more.  If you don't do that, you can't earn a profit...

Comment: **<comments deleted>** [Comments](http://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) are not to be used for debating.  If you wish to debate, go to [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Extract from fatwa:

> **There is no limit to profits in trading, rather the matter is subject
>   to supply and demand.** But it is good for the Muslim, whether he is a
>   trader or not, to be easy going in buying and selling, and not to
>   exploit the opportunity of his counterpart’s carelessness to cheat him
>   in buying and selling. Rather he should pay attention to the rights of
>   his Muslims brothers.

Source of fatwa: [islamqa.com](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/47889)